# Input “Infinite Value” option in spin control

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, users, human-interface-guideline, hci

In my UI if a user selects to allow multiple , he checks the check box next to “Multiple ”. When this check box is selected, “Maximum” option becomes enabled. Here user can define how many options can be done.

I want to allow my user to do “Infinite” .
The option that I have decided to use for this thing is that if user does not type anything, “-” appears in edit box showing that there is not limit and “Unlimited” is allowed.  Else user can type a number or user spin control in order to specify the limit up to he is allowed.

Option can be anything either using spin control or any other thing

Comment: Simply display "infinite" or "unlimited" instead of "-" and add a corresponding combobox value. It will be much more clear.

Comment: `unlimited` is also used in most torrent downloaders when setting upload and download speed. If that's too long you have `&infin;` or `&#8734;` for the infinity symbol.

Comment: Many developers write -1 or 0 for unlimited. But this is not user friendly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am wary of any solution where the user has to remember that inputting x really means y. If the "infinite" or "unlimited" state can't be unambiguously represented by the spinner control I would consider using another one specifically for the "unlimited mapping" use case. Perhaps have another checkbox for unlimited that, when selected, disables / greys out the spinner?